# Extract Value between XML tags with SED

Tags: c#, windows, sed, grep

I am receiving data from a server in the following format:

```
gin</type><sessionId>1601</sessionId><directory><default>DepthOfBook</default><study type="DepthOfBook"/
```

How can I extract the value 1601 from this string? I have been trying the following, but am lost with the proper SED syntax:

```
    sed -n "/sessionId/,/\/sessionId/p" 

    sed -e "s/<sessionId/\n/g"| sed -n "/sessionId/,/\/sessionId/p" 

    sed -e "s/</\n/g"| sed -n "/sessionId/,/sessionId/p"
```

How can I extract this value (and generally a value between two XML tags when the string is one, long multiline string)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/<sessionId>/!d;s//\n/;s/[^\n]*\n//;:a;$!{/<\/sessionId>/!N;//!ba};y/\n/ /;s/<\/sessionId>/\n/;P;D' file
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this would work:

```
 sed -e 's/<\/sessionId>/<\/sessionId>\n/g' | sed -n 's/.*<sessionId>\([^<]*\)<\/sessionId>.*/\1/p'
```

First part is because sed tries to eat up as much of a single line as possible when matching, this will find all `sessionId` occurences and split them up on a line on its own.

Next part matches stuff between the `sessionId` tags.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using [XPath](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_syntax.asp), which is an XML query language. If you have the Perl [XML::XPath](http://search.cpan.org/dist/XML-XPath/XPath.pm) module installed then you could simply use the following command in your shell:

```
xpath -q -e '//sessionId/text()' <input_file>
```

Comment: That is given the data is well formed XML?

Comment: The author states that the tags are XML so I assume he has an XML document (otherwise there is no use in stating that the tags are XML), which should always be [well-formed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML#Well-formedness_and_error-handling), otherwise it is no XML document.